# How do I sum up each Month of data for each product?

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, sql-order-by

I have a set of data such as:

```
Date        Product    Volume
01-01-2020  A          5
02-01-2020  A          25
03-01-2020  B          20
02-01-2020  B          10
04-01-2020  C          5
02-02-2020  A          30
02-02-2020  B          25
01-02-2020  C          25
01-02-2020  C          40
04-02-2020  C          100
01-03-2020  A          5
01-03-2020  B          0
01-03-2020  A          50
```

The output would be something like:

```
Date        Product    Monthly Volume
01-01-2020  A          30
01-01-2020  B          40
01-01-2020  C          5
01-02-2020  A          30
01-02-2020  B          25
01-02-2020  C          165
01-03-2020  A          55
01-03-2020  B          0
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks for all the help in advance =)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: As in the name of the database? Sorry still very new to SQL

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) month and product, e.g.

```
SELECT Product, MONTH(Date), Sum(Volume) As Monthly Volume
FROM table
GROUP BY MONTH(Date), Product
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for thanks. Do you know how i would keep the year in the Date column?

Comment: You could add another column which reads the year from date, such as `SELECT MONTH(Date), YEAR(Date)` and then `GROUP BY MONTH(Date), YEAR(Date)`

Comment: thanks for the help, is there no way to keep it in one column in a similar format to:
01-2020,
02-2020,
03-2020
etc

Comment: Take a look at concat(column1, column2)  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_concat.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have tested the query in oracle.

```
select distinct to_char(dateval,'Month') as month,product,
sum(volume) 
over (PARTITION  by to_char(date,'Month'),product)as vol 
from test order by product;
```